# Webdriver.io: acceptInsecureCerts and acceptSslCerts capability options seem to have no effect

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate, webdriver-io

I'm migrating from webdriver.io 4 to 6.
I set the capability options in wdio.conf.js file:

```
capabilities: [
    {
        maxInstances: 5,
        browserName: 'chrome',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
    },
],
```

Then I call a website with a self certificate and still get "Your connection is not secure" warning.

How can I avoid it?
With the 4 version it went fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass as chrome argument on start:

```
{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    maxInstances: 5,
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was able to resolve it by adding the below property to the capabilities

```
strictSSL: false
```